# Smalltalk How to Fill 2d array with random numbers?

Tags: smalltalk

In java, or C# filling of the  2d array is possible with two nested for loop, but in smalltalk I can't seem to find the way to do the same. 
Could anyone help me out?

[array filling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ0IK.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Matrix` and create it as:

```
| random |
random := Random new.
^ Matrix
   rows: rowNumber
   columns: columnNumber
   tabulate: [ :i :j | random next ]
```

where i and j are indexes of the element (that I'm not using in the example)

If you really want to do something with 2d arrays I'd suggest you to do something like this:

```
| random |
random := Random new.
^ (1 to: rowNumber) collect: [ :i | 
   (1 to: columnNumber) collect: [ :j |
      random next ]
```

You can also traverse a matrix after creation:

```
| random matrix |
random := Random new.
matrix := Matrix rows: rowNumber columns: columnNumber.
martix indicesCollect:  [ :i :j | random next ].
^ matrix
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping words!

Comment: @user3508536 you can also upvote if it makes any sense :)